# What kind of algorithms are appropriate for this sort of medium-dimensional integration problem?

Tags: expected-value, high-dimensional, numerical-integration

I'm trying to model a situation in which an agent must select one of several choices (not more than ten). Each choice is associated with a vector, known to the agent, representing its effectiveness in each of 8-15 categories. The agent's choice will be scored as a linear combination of its effectiveness in each category.

The goal is to select the choice with the highest expected value, given that the weights for the linear combination will be chosen uniformly from all possibilities where:

- The weight for each category falls within a range known to the agent ahead of time.
- The sum of the weights of all the categories is exactly 1. (Since they represent the fraction of the total score determined by each category.)

It's easy to express the solution to this problem mathematically. It simply means integrating the dot product of each choice's effectiveness vector with every point in the space of weights (the intersection of a hyperbox and the hyperplane $x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n=1$, and choosing the greatest result.

The question is: what kind of algorithm can I use to compute (approximately) that integral? The dimensionality of the problem made me think that naive approaches might be too slow, so I read up on various techniques for numerical integration in higher dimensions (basic quadrature, quasi-Monte Carlo, Markov chain Monte Carlo, Smolyak quadrature, etc.)

However, I haven't been able to get a good grasp on what sort of problems  each technique is appropriate for. In particular, it's not clear to me what 'high-dimensional' means in the context of these algorithms. (10D? 100D? 1000D?). None of the sources I found gave even an order of magnitude. Could anyone with more experience with this sort of problem point me in the right direction?

**EDIT:** It was requested that I provide the form of the integral itself. For a vector of minimum weights $\vec{m}$, a vector of maximum weights $\vec{M}$, and a choice's effectiveness vector $\vec{c}$, all $n$-dimensional, it is:
$$\int_W{\vec{c}\cdot\vec{w}\,dW} = \int_W{c_1 w_1 + c_2 w_2 +\cdots+ c_n w_n\,dW}$$ Where $W$ is the set of points that satisfy $m_i \leq x_i \leq M_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$ and lie on the hyperplane $x_0+x_1+\cdots+x_n=1$.

Comment: Could you update the question to include the actual expression for the integral?

Comment: @user20160 Sure, though I don't think there's any way to obtain an explicit form for the region of integration, which is the most interesting part.